# Why does this custom jQuery prompt repeat its callback action n-times every n-th time it's used?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<html>
    <div id="pnl_prompt" style="display:none; background-color:#808080">
        <b id="lbl_prompt_title">Prompt</b> <br />
        <span id="lbl_prompt_name" class="right">Field:</span>  <input id="txt_prompt_field" type="text"/>  <hr />
        <input id="btn_prompt_ok" type="button" value="OK"/>
        <input id="btn_prompt_cancel" type="button" value="Cancel"/>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function myPrompt(title, name, isPassword, callback){
                $("#btn_prompt_ok").click(function(){
                    $("#pnl_prompt").css("display","none");
                    ENTERED_VALUE = $("#txt_prompt_field").val();
                    if(callback)    callback();
                });
                $("#btn_prompt_cancel").click(function(){
                    $("#pnl_prompt").css("display","none");
                    ENTERED_VALUE = null;
                    $("#txt_prompt_field").val("");
                });

                ENTERED_VALUE = null;
                $("#lbl_prompt_title").html(title);
                $("#lbl_prompt_name").html(name+":");
                if(isPassword)  $("#txt_prompt_field").prop("type", "password");
                $("#pnl_prompt").css("display","block").css({position:"absolute",left:"100px",top:"100px"});
                $("#txt_prompt_field").val("").focus();
            }
        </script>
    </div>
</html>
```

The above div lays out a text field with OK and Cancel buttons. The myPrompt function makes the div appear, and declares the OK/Cancel button actions. OK stores the text input value to window.ENTERED_VALUE, then hides the div. Consider the following test javascript call:

javascript:myPrompt("Hello", "World", false, function(){alert(ENTERED_VALUE);});

It's supposed to alert the entered value after the user submits his value through the OK button. It does so, but if you run the call again there are 2 alerts. Again brings 3 alerts, etc. How is this happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well... you assign a new click handler every time you call `myPrompt` with these lines:

```
function myPrompt(title, name, isPassword, callback){
        $("#btn_prompt_ok").click(function(){ // new callback for clicking!
            $("#pnl_prompt").css("display","none");
            ENTERED_VALUE = $("#txt_prompt_field").val();
            if(callback)    callback();
        });

        $("#btn_prompt_cancel").click(function(){ // new callback for clicking!
            ...
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer! So I must know, how do I overwrite my click handlers instead of duplicating them? Do I use .unbind("click")?